# jQuery Parsing of non-uniform HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing, cheerio

I'm tasked with parsing data from static HTML pages generated from data which has been "misplaced".

The meat of the HTML follows the following pattern:

```
<div class="product-detail">
    <h1>Product Name <span>Company</span></h1>
    <p>
        <strong>Description</strong>
        EZ use widget
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Location</strong>
        China
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Width</strong>
        10" <span>(26cm)</span>
        <strong>Height</strong>
        9"
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Category</strong>
        <a>Widget</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The "Product Name" and "Company" are easy enough

```
var productDetail = $('div.product-detail');

var data = {
    name: productDetail.children('h1').clone().children().remove().end().text(),
    company: productDetail.children('h1').children('span').text()
};
```

My problem is with the details. The description name is always in a `<strong>` tag but the actual description is sometimes wrapped in other tags. Furthermore, the descriptions sometimes share a `<p>` tag (width, height above) and descriptions vary by product.

I've tried the obvious suspects

```
productDetails.contents().each( ... )
```

recursive parsing and even pure DOM manipulation, but end up with garbage especially if descriptions share a `<p>` tag. Unfortunately my jQuery skills have let me down.

What's the simplest way to grab the `<strong>` with the text (perhaps imbedded in a tag) immediately after it to produce the follow JSON object

```
{
  name: "Product Name",
  company: "Company",
  Description: "EZ use widget",
  Location: "China",
  Width: '10"',
  Height: '9"',
  Category: "Widget"
}
```

I think I'm too close to the problem and missing the obvious answer.

Comment: [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) may be of some use here.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.contents()` will return an array of html elements.

```
$(".product-detail > p:eq(2)").contents()
```

Each of these has `.textContent` and `.nodeName` properties.

Good luck with if-else's related to determining what's what before that object assembly!